# show that matrices sharing a minimal polynom, also share the Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of the same dimension.
Show that they have the same minimal polynom if and only if they have the same Jordan form.

(btw, is it possible to prove with the charastaristic polynom instead?)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements are wrong - the Jordan form is a full invariant of similarity and contains more information than just the minimal polynomial or the characteristic polynomial. For a counter-example, consider the matrices

$$ A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right), \,\,\, B = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right). $$

Comment: but isn't it true that matrices that share the minimal polynomial are similair?

Comment: @YotamAlon : levap has given you two matrices that are not similar, but which share the same minimal polynomial.

Comment: sorry, you are correct